# Find direction vectors of a plan

Tags: geometry

First, I am a newbie in maths so please forgive me if I am not being as much rigorous as you would like.

#### The problem

I am creating a ray-tracer and I need to model a screen in a 3D space (which is basically an infinite set of points within a part of a plan -ie. a surface-). And I want to get the coordinates of all the points of my screen separated by a certain distance (let's say 1).

Here's what it looks like

[image: Screenshot]

(original at: http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1396379573.png)

#### What I tried already

I thought about getting the direction vectors (with a norm of 1) of the plan and apply translations from a know point on this plan to get all the points, but I can't manage to find directions vectors.

#### What I know

- I have a direction vector of known coordinates which I know is orthogonal to my screen.
- I have the coordinates of one point (the "center") of this screen.
- I have the "width" and the "height" of this screen

To be more clear in the discussion, let 
$\vec{u} \left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\\c\end{matrix}\right)$ 
be the normal vector to the surface $S$ and $\theta$ its rotation angle (accordingly to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation)). Also, let $A(d, e, f)$ be the center of the screen and $w$ and $h$ be respectively the width and the height of the screen.

#### What I want

I'm looking for a possibly better solution than the one I thought about,

or -

I am looking for how the get the two direction vectors of this screen (knowing that they can't be "random" orthogonal vectors of this plan, since it's more of a surface and I want to have the possibility to apply a translation).

Do not hesitate to ask for more information since it may be unclear.

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then I think there is not enough information here. Suppose the center of the screen is at the origin, and suppose the vector $(1,0,0)$ is orthogonal to the screen. We still have a degree of freedom unaccounted for, which is the angle of rotation about the $(1,0,0)$ axis.

Comment: You are right. Let's say I know theta (accordingly to this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) which defines the rotation of my normal vector, how can I then get the coordinates points?

Comment: I don't see how this gives enough by itself. Do you know the coordinates of any of the corners of the screen? Or do you know a vector that points along either edge?

Comment: I would suggest defining your variables explicitly with symbols so that it's easier to understand and discuss your problem. This may also help reveal unstated assumptions or missing constraints, as @JasonZimba has been describing.

Comment: Dan > Just added notations.

Jason > I could know the upper right corner (even if I would like to avoid it, I can manage to get its coordinates)